# Decode JSON property names to list strings instead of binary strings using Jiffy in Erlang

Tags: json, erlang, jiffy

I have a tuple generated using [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) library.

For example : `jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}">>).` results in
 `{[{<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>}]}`

I want `<<"foo">>` to be `"foo"`

Is there a way for converting the `<<"foo">>` to `"foo"`?

Basically I want to convert this:

`[{<<"t">>,<<"getWebPagePreview">>},{<<"message">>,<<"google.com">>}]`

into this:

`[{"t",<<"getWebPagePreview">>},{"message",<<"google.com">>}]`

note: consider this to be a very large list, and I want an efficient solution.

Answer (score 4):

there is a function to transform a binary `<<"hello">>` into a list `"hello"`:

```
1> binary_to_list(<<"hello">>).
"hello"
2> L = [{<<"t">>,<<"getWebPagePreview">>},{<<"message">>,<<"google.com">>}].
[{<<"t">>,<<"getWebPagePreview">>},
 {<<"message">>,<<"google.com">>}]
```

You can apply this to your list using a list comprehension:

```
3> [{binary_to_list(X),Y} || {X,Y} <- L].
[{"t",<<"getWebPagePreview">>},{"message",<<"google.com">>}]
4>
```

you can embed this in a function:

```
convert(List) ->
    F = fun({X,Y}) -> {binary_to_list(X),Y} end,
    [F(Tuple) || Tuple <- List].
```

Comment: Is it the best way we can do this? Since the string is very large, I'm concerned about efficiency. Is there any other way, like using c language in combination with Erlang? or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Because (when) order of elements doesn't matter the most efficient version is

```
convert({List}) ->
    {convert(List, [])}.

convert([], Acc) -> Acc;
convert([{X, Y}|T], Acc) ->
    convert(T, [{binary_to_list(X), Y}|Acc]).
```

When you want to preserve order of element strightforward version with list comprehension

```
convert({List}) ->
    {[{binary_to_list(X), Y} || {X, Y} <- List]}.
```

is the (almost) exact equivalent of

```
convert({List}) ->
    {convert_(List)}.

convert_([]) -> [];
convert_([{X, Y}|T]) ->
    [{binary_to_list(X), Y}|convert_(T)].
```

Comment: Is it the best way to do this? I'm concerned about efficiency of solution because string is very large.

Comment: For such example you can benchmark the different solutions: `timer:tc(module_name,convert_method,[List])`. But yes you will not find faster solutions.